# Counter char script for many fields

Tags: javascript, char, counter

Hi I want use this script to count char in form with many fields,
but not want duplicate code, I want use only one code for all fields,
how can pass to javascript name fields count and display this count...
As one counter for many fields input type...
thanks
Salvatore

```
<script>
 function countChar(val) {
     var len = val.value.length;
     if (len >= 66) {
     val.value = val.value.substring(0, 66);
     } else {
     $('#charNum').text(65 - len);
     }
  };
</script>

<div id="charNum"></div>
<input type="text" name="name_var1" value="" maxlength="66" onkeyup="countChar(this)" />

<div id="charNum"></div>
<input type="text" name="name_var2" value="" maxlength="66" onkeyup="countChar(this)" />

<div id="charNum"></div>
<input type="text" name="name_var3" value="" maxlength="66" onkeyup="countChar(this)" />
```

Comment: This is not php

Comment: Simply make one function and call it for each field, doing that you will not have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are using ids several times. Try to work with classes and generate the selectors from the class name of the element.

```
    <script>
     function countChar(val) {
         var len = val.value.length;
         if (len >= 66) {
            val.value = val.value.substring(0, 66);
         } else {
            $('.' + val.className + '_charNum').text(65 - len);
         }
      };
    </script>

    <div class="name_var1_charNum"></div>
    <input class="name_var1" type="text" name="name_var1" value="" maxlength="66" onkeyup="countChar(this)" />

    <div class="name_var2_charNum"></div>
    <input class="name_var2" type="text" name="name_var2" value="" maxlength="66" onkeyup="countChar(this)" />

    <div class="name_var3_charNum"></div>
    <input class="name_var3" type="text" name="name_var3" value="" maxlength="66" onkeyup="countChar(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you do need to display characters left value for each field (depending on max-length) and restrict user from adding extra characters (more than allowed limit). Probably that's what you need.

```
<div class="countable-item">
    <div class="char-num"></div>
    <input type="text" name="any" class="countable" max-length="66" />
</div>

<div class="countable-item">
    <div class="char-num"></div>
    <input type="text" name="any2" class="countable" max-length="66" />
</div>

<script>
    (function($){
        var restrictMaxLength = function () {
            var maxLength = $(this).attr('max-length'),
                currentValue = $(this).val(),
                currentLength = currentValue.length;

            if (currentLength >= maxLength) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        displayCountCharacters = function () {
            var maxLength = $(this).attr('max-length'),
                currentValue = $(this).val(),
                currentLength = currentValue.length;

            $(this).closest('.countable-item')
                .find('.char-num')
                .text(maxLength - currentLength);
        };

    $(document)
        .on('keypress', '.countable', restrictMaxLength)
        .on('keyup', '.countable', displayCountCharacters); 
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```